# What is the difference between <exec_depend> and <run_depend>?

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm pretty new here but wanted to let you guys know I had en error while just follwing the tutorial.

When I reached the "msg and srv" part (  http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv ) I encountered an error.

I was asked to put

`<exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>`

in my package.xml file.

When I entered

```
$ rosmsg show beginner_tutorials/Num
```

This was the error I got :

```
  File "/opt/ros/lunar/bin/rosmsg", line 35, in <module>
    rosmsg.rosmsgmain()
  File "/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmsg/__init__.py", line 754, in rosmsgmain
    sys.exit(rosmsg_cmd_show(ext, full, command))
  File "/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmsg/__init__.py", line 621, in rosmsg_cmd_show
    found_msgs = list(rosmsg_search(rospack, mode, arg))
  File "/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmsg/__init__.py", line 565, in rosmsg_search
    for p, path in iterate_packages(rospack, mode):
  File "/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmsg/__init__.py", line 541, in iterate_packages
    package_paths = _get_package_paths(p, rospack)
  File "/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmsg/__init__.py", line 554, in _get_package_paths
    results = find_in_workspaces(search_dirs=['share'], project=pkgname, first_match_only=True, workspace_to_source_spaces=_catkin_workspace_to_source_spaces, source_path_to_packages=_catkin_source_path_to_packages)
  File "/opt/ros/lunar/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/find_in_workspaces.py", line 143, in find_in_workspaces
    source_path_to_packages[source_path] = find_packages(source_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py", line 83, in find_packages
    packages = find_packages_allowing_duplicates(basepath, exclude_paths=exclude_paths, exclude_subspaces=exclude_subspaces, warnings=warnings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py", line 110, in find_packages_allowing_duplicates
    packages[path] = parse_package(os.path.join(basepath, path), warnings=warnings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 379, in parse_package
    return parse_package_string(f.read(), filename, warnings=warnings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 550, in parse_package_string
    raise InvalidPackage('Error(s) in %s:%s' % (filename, ''.join(['\n- %s' % e for e in errors])))
catkin_pkg.package.InvalidPackage: Invalid package manifest "/home/enslab/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/package.xml": Error(s) in /home/enslab/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/package.xml:
- The manifest (with format version 1) must not contain the following tags: exec_depend
```

In a youtube video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4bpTU_bdPs ) I saw

`<run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>`

was used instead. This worked perfectly fine for me.

What is the difference between the two of them exactly? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283123/what-is-the-difference-between-%3Cexec_depend%3E-and-%3Crun_depend%3E-?/) by [Fldeg](https://answers.ros.org/users/33761/fldeg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2018-02-19

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is new convention in catkin package format 2. Basically the `<run_depend>` tag was replaced by `<exec_depend>`.

To define format 2 package replace `<package>` tag in your `package.xml` file with `<package format="2">`.

For more information have a look at the documentation [here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html) and migration guide from format 1 to format 2 [here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/migrating_from_format_1.html).

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2018-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8